# Proposal to edit the Close-Reason "Not about Ubuntu" to also include questions about other *mobile* OS

Tags: discussion, feature-request, close-reasons, scope

The reason why I am proposing this is that I saw [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/631154) which is about an android app that the user falsely expected to find in the Ubuntu-touch repository.

My reaction would have been to close as off-topic because it is not about Ubuntu, but android. However, it was not possible because the reason only mentions desktop OS. This is probably not the best example, but you can see the point:

We have users that talk about other desktop/server-OS than Ubuntu (Windows, OSX), and we will also have an increasing amount of users talking about other mobile-OS like android, WindowsPhone or iOS, I assume. For them, there are the sites [WindowsPhone](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/) and [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) (and [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) for iOS) respectively.

So in my opinion, we should expand the close reason "off topic because not about Ubuntu" to not only cover the several non-Ubuntu desktop OS, but also the non-Ubuntu mobile OS.

What do you think? Upvote if you agree, downvote if you disagree. If you want to add something, please comment or answer.

Comment: I agree, but, android is not ubuntu so I think we are covered. I would leave a comment sending them to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions for android. I do not think we can list all non-ubuntu OS, "not ubuntu" covers it. I am not sure of the offical status of ubuntu phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can hardly list all operating systems for all hardware that are not Ubuntu! That would mean listing Windows, non-Ubuntu Linux, OSX, UNIX, Haiku, BeOs, all UNIX-like systems, iOS, Windows Mobile (or whatever it's called), Android, Blackberry, that Nokia system, various embedded OSs etc, etc.

We say quite clearly that "Not Ubuntu" = off topic, I see no reason to list the dozens of systems that can be non Ubuntu. Just close as off topic, the message "This is not about Ubuntu" is about as clear as it gets. In any case, people posting Windows Mobile questions on a site called Ask *Ubuntu* are probably beyond help anyway.

Comment: Okay, I see your point and agree, but I think we should then at least modify it, so that it includes "Ubuntu touch" as on-topic and "other mobile OS" as off-topic. There is nothing about mobile OS in the comment yet.

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is implied to be Ubuntu by namesake, no?  Do we really need to add it to the close reason?  @ByteCommander  The same logic of 'Not Ubuntu' applies to Mobile OSes as well.